# React: Event-triggered Ajax call in componentDidUpdate or render creates infinite loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have an Ajax call which is triggered by an event(click). It works as it's supposed to(it will populate a table), however it simply keeps doing the Ajax call all the time, eventually eating out memory which is unsustainable, of course.

What's the issue here? I have tried putting the Ajax call inside `componentDidMount`, but the result was the same, if it's triggered the Ajax call will just explode(5-10 calls per second).

I could do a hack and just make a count and stop at 1, but that's not the right way to solve it(I need to find the root cause :) )

Sample code:

```
let Sample = React.createClass({

    getInitialState : function () {
        return{
            data: [],
        };
    },


    ajaxCall : function(someValue) { // Ajax call which sets data
        $.ajax({
    // ... 
        });
    },

    renderTable(value, index) { // Populates the table
    // .. 
    },

    render : function () {

        let tabledata = this.state.data;

        if (tableData) {
            this.ajaxCall(this.props.someValue); // This goes into an infinite loop
            return (
                <Popover id="popover-positioned-scrolling-left" title={this.props.someValue}>
                    <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Header 1</th>
                            <th>Header 2</th>
                            <th>Header 3</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {tableData.map(this.renderTable)}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </Popover>
            )
        }
        else {
            return <div></div>
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: You should not invoke such command directly from `render` function. I it should be called after some event/click/`componentDidMount` or some such and use `this.setState` to set data to be displayed. I think You should provide more code to get full investigation of whats the cause here.

Comment: If the ajax code is changing the state then it'll go to infinite loop because: 1. `render` is called when state was changed, 2. ajax call is called within that `render` function, 3. again ajax call is changing state which invokes `render` and the loop is going... If You want to fetch the data in some period of times, You should use timeout/interval mechanisms

Comment: I see that. Actually setting `this.state.data = data` fixes it, although I'm sure it's a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you do `setstate`, it will triggered `re-rendering` of component. Inside

```
ajaxCall : function(countryIso3) { // Ajax call which sets data
        $.ajax({
    // ... 
        });
    },
```

You are using `setState` to set the data in state variable, that will call `render` again, and inside `render` you are again making the `api` call, then  again `setState` ......That's why infinite loop.

Simple solution of that problem is do the api call inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request.

[Regrading State Update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

**Update:**

Do the api call inside the onClick event.

Lets say, you want to call the api on click of any text, then write it like this:

```
 <p onClick={this.ajaxCall}>Click me to fetch the data</p>

 ajaxCall : function(countryIso3) { // Ajax call which sets data
     $.ajax({
       // ... 
     });
 }
```

Comment: That makes sense. But how would I bind the data from the ajax call to `this.state.data` without using `setState` ?

Comment: Hmm... Ok, it was simpler than I thought. I simply had to use `this.stata.data = data` instead of setState..

Comment: nope, that's the bad way, do not mutate the state variable directly, always use setState, check the updated answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure that'll work; that'll only run once... And the component won't really re-mount just because the event happens?

Comment: you want to fetch the data just once, correct ?? that lifecycle method will work properly in that case, when you do setState it will update the state and render the component again.

Comment: no, the ajax call is made every time an event happens which is triggered by a click on a certain component.

Comment: so You should invoke the ajax method on the click. In Your code it's invoked every time view is rendered.

Comment: @AdamSzmyd is right, you should do the api call inside that onClick event, in ur present code it is happening every time component renders.

Comment: do the first api call inside `componentDidMount` then do the `api` call inside `onClick` event, it will work proper :) let me know if you face any issue in that.

Comment: There is no api call to do when it mounts: Nothing is displayed. The table is populated based on what the user clicks(so it listens to this event). I get where you're coming from but I don't think it's applicable in my case(but understandable since it's just sample code)

Comment: in that case also, this solution is a generic one. since you don't want any api call during initial mounting, don't use that lifecycle method, and do the api call inside click event not directly from render method. it will work.

Comment: check the updated answer, how to make api call on click of any text of any other event :)

Comment: Indeed, but it's passed as a prop from another component, so it still won't quite do the job for me. Thanks regardless.

Comment: in that case also, if you are passing the event from parent component, then do one thing, do the api call in parent component and return the data to child component.